# Tool to manage multiple characters

Tags: database, game

I absolutely love games where you can create custom characters, particularly ones where you create multiple characters that exist together rather then just customising the protagonist (e.g. the Sims or XCOM vs Mass Effect).

Because I make so many characters, both original and recreations of characters from other games, movies etc, it can be complicated to manage everyone. Sometimes I just want to view all the characters from one category without scrolling through the dozens of characters I've made chronologically. It's also a pain to keep track of which characters I've made in which games.

Is there a tool or website that lets you create a profile for each character with their details (name, age, gender, origin, which games I have made in, etc) with the ability to filter by name, or from which category they belong to/tags assigned to them, for example? I am unaware of any, and don't want to have to code my own Web app and host a database. It may not be a character specific tool, a generic database tool may do, but I cannot find a good one for free.

Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1):

[Memento Database](https://mementodatabase.com/) is/has an Android app that is basically just a local database. You create your own custom tables that you can fill with your information, and so on.